# Allow customer too attach image to contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below contact form and I would like to allow customers to send me an image as an attachment. I have added the field to the form but don't understand the following -

- What migration do I create?
- How do I attach the image to the
  mailer?

#### View

```
<%= simple_form_for @inquiry, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :spam, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :phone %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :message %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %> ## Attachment input here
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

#### Controller

```
  def new
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new
  end

  def create
    redirect_to new_inquiry_path and return if params[:spam].present?
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(inquiry_params)
    if @inquiry.valid?
      InquiryMailer.admin(@inquiry).deliver
      redirect_to inquiries_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def inquiry_params
    params.require(:inquiry).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
  end
```

#### Model

```
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :phone, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true
```

#### inquiry_mailer.rb

```
class InquiryMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@foo.com"

  def admin(inquiry)
    @inquiry = inquiry
    mail to: "hello@foo.co.uk", subject: "Website Inquiry"
  end
end
```

#### admin.text.erb

```
Website Inquiry
=========

Name: <%= @inquiry.name %>
Phone: <%= @inquiry.name %>
E-Mail: <%= @inquiry.email %>
Message: <%= @inquiry.message %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of ActionMailer here

Ill provide an answer based upon your existing setup

You  need to edit your mailer to look something like this

```
class InquiryMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS'] #I like to keep my email address hidden

  def admin(inquiry)
    @inquiry= inquiry
     if inquiry.file
       attachment_name = inquiry.file.original_filename
       attachments[attachment_name] = inquiry.file.read
     end
     mail(to: ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS'], subject: 'Website Inquiry')
  end
end
```

You can keep admin.text.erb as it is and your controller stays the same

and within your form_for dont forget to add

```
<%= simple_form_for @inquiry, :method => :post, :multipart => true do |f| %>
```

so you the attachment can be added

Think thats it off the top of my head

Hope that helps, any questions then please ask

Comment: Thanks @Richlewis, i'm not if I follow you 100%. I have added my existing mailer and mail view so you can see what I currently have.

Comment: i have edited my answer so it is inline with the setup you have

Comment: cool, if you need any help with anything else in the future feel free to follow me on twitter and ask away